# Network Access Denied on iomega StorCenter Pro

Tags: windows-xp, network-attached-storage

This is a question about my home network, so any help would be appreciated.  I hope this is the correct forum for such a question.

I have what seems to be (and was until yesterday) a fully functional iomega StorCenterPro.  I can access it's UI via firefox by typing in the IP address it is sitting at.

I think I have set up accounts correctly for me and my wife.  The account names do not correspond to the account names on our computers.

We are running WinXP on VMWare on top of OS X.

When I try mapping network drive (and connect as different user), it pauses for a second and then tells me Network Access Denied.

What am I missing?

Thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have Samba problems. Be sure that you export your share in `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and it has proper permissions (for debug purposes I recommend you to make it public). Also you should check `smbd` and `nmbd` running:

```
$ pgrep smbd
4686
$ pgrep nmbd
4678
```